# Is there a way to create a Membership Status for memberships that have recently been renewed?

Tags: civimember, status

We currently use the membership status "NEW" to identify recent membership signups.  For various reasons, we also need a membership status to identify those who have recently renewed.  As a workaround, I'm creating a smart group for the activity "Membership Renewal" but it seems that a status would be better.  Anyone know how to do this or if it is possible?

Comment: There is some work underway to revamp membership periods in CiviCRM that would support this!  You may want to talk to Jamie Novick at Compucorp to make sure your use case is considered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not really possible to have a status for the `Renew` state because the `Start event` used for status rules is based on one of the following date :

- start date : this date is updated only when there is a gap between the last end date and the new renewal date... if there is no gap, which is the most frequent case, there will be no update
- end date : updated any time the membership is successfully renewed / mainly used for "grace" / "expired" status
- member since : this date is not updated by the system at all so it is used for new membership

So, without development, the only way i can think of having this kind of status is to manually update the start date every time you renew (which probably defeat the purpose).

Then, you can define :

- `Start Event` to `start date`
- `Start Event Adjustment` to be 0 (start at the renewal date)
- `End Event` to be **start date** again
- `End Event Adjustment` to be 1 month or the period you'd like it to lasts
- `Current Membership` should be **checked** because obviously, membership with those status are valid

Please put the new `Renew` rule **above** the `Current` status by changing the `Order` because CiviCRM test the rules one by one and stop at the first matching item.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Yes, I see how this would work but you're right, it would ultimately defeat the purpose by removing another feature, start date.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't walked through the details, but CiviRules lets you do things with membership statuses. You may want to walk the logic through and see if there is a way to get what you want or close to what you want with that for now.

Comment: All I'm aware of is the ability to set s condition in Civirules based on membership status, but it would great if it were possible to set the membership status as an action.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong - you need to create a new membership status - please use the below link

administer -> civimember -> membership status rules
or 
.../civicrm/admin/member/membershipStatus?reset=1

you can find a list of existing membership status - just add new and create one saying "Renewed" and you need to set the membership status to renewed whenever a new member signup

Also if you have "Update Membership Statuses" schedule job running which will reset the status based on the rules whenever the job runs

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: I am not sure this helps. how does Damon do the configuration so this Status only kicks in after a renewal?

Comment: only way to implement this would be to writing a post hook in an extension